# Repartition Dask DataFrame to get even partitions

Tags: python, dataframe, parquet, dask

I have a [Dask DataFrames](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe.html%22Dask%20DataFrame%22) that contains index which is not unique (`client_id`). Repartitioning and resetting index ends up with very uneven partitions - some contains only a few rows, some thousands. For instance the following code:

```
for p in range(ddd.npartitions):
    print(len(ddd.get_partition(p)))
```

prints out something like that:

> ```
> 55
> 17
> 5
> 41
> 51
> 1144
> 4391
> 75153
> 138970
> 197105
> 409466
> 415925
> 486076
> 306377
> 543998
> 395974
> 530056
> 374293
> 237
> 12
> 104
> 52
> 28
> ```

My DataFrame is one-hot encoded and has over 500 columns. Larger partitions don't fit in memory. I wanted to repartition the DataFrame to have partitions even in size. Do you know an efficient way to do this?

**EDIT 1**

Simple reproduce:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.arange(0,10000),'y':np.arange(0,10000)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.append(np.arange(0,4995),np.arange(5000,10000,1000)),'y2':np.arange(0,10000,2)})
dd_df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10).set_index('x')
dd_df2= dd.from_pandas(df2, npartitions=5).set_index('x')
new_ddf=dd_df.merge(dd_df2, how='right')
#new_ddf = new_ddf.reset_index().set_index('x')
#new_ddf = new_ddf.repartition(npartitions=2)
new_ddf.divisions
for p in range(new_ddf.npartitions):
    print(len(new_ddf.get_partition(p)))
```

Note the last partitions (one single element):

> ```
> 1000
> 1000
> 1000
> 1000
> 995
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 1
> ```

Even when we uncomment the commented lines, partitions remain uneven in the size.

**Edit II: Walkoround**

Simple wlakoround can be achieved by the following code.
Is there a more elgant way to do this (more in a Dask way)?

```
def repartition(ddf, npartitions=None):
    MAX_PART_SIZE = 100*1024

    if npartitions is None:
        npartitions = ddf.npartitions

    one_row_size = sum([dt.itemsize for dt in ddf.dtypes])
    length = len(ddf)

    requested_part_size = length/npartitions*one_row_size
    if requested_part_size <= MAX_PART_SIZE:
        np = npartitions
    else:
        np = length*one_row_size/MAX_PART_SIZE

    chunksize = int(length/np)


    vc = ddf.index.value_counts().to_frame(name='count').compute().sort_index()

    vsum = 0
    divisions = [ddf.divisions[0]]
    for i,v in vc.iterrows():
        vsum+=v['count']
        if vsum > chunksize:
            divisions.append(i)
            vsum = 0
    divisions.append(ddf.divisions[-1])


    return ddf.repartition(divisions=divisions, force=True)
```

Comment: Did you try [repartition](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.repartition)?

Comment: @Primer, yes I did, but it has no effect. The problem seems to be connected with the fact that the dataframe is read from parquet.

Comment: @Szymon why do you think it's related to the fact that it's read from parquet?

Answer (score 10):

You're correct that `.repartition` won't do the trick since it doesn't handle any of the logic for computing divisions and just tries to combine the existing partitions wherever possible. Here's a solution I came up with for the same problem:

```
def _rebalance_ddf(ddf):
    """Repartition dask dataframe to ensure that partitions are roughly equal size.

    Assumes `ddf.index` is already sorted.
    """
    if not ddf.known_divisions:  # e.g. for read_parquet(..., infer_divisions=False)
        ddf = ddf.reset_index().set_index(ddf.index.name, sorted=True)
    index_counts = ddf.map_partitions(lambda _df: _df.index.value_counts().sort_index()).compute()
    index = np.repeat(index_counts.index, index_counts.values)
    divisions, _ = dd.io.io.sorted_division_locations(index, npartitions=ddf.npartitions)
    return ddf.repartition(divisions=divisions)
```

The internal function `sorted_division_locations` does what you want already, but it only works on an actual list-like, not a lazy `dask.dataframe.Index`. This avoids pulling the full index in case there are many duplicates and instead just gets the counts and reconstructs locally from that.

If your dataframe is so large that even the index won't fit in memory then you'd need to do something even more clever.

Comment: Awesome! Saved me some time. Thanks!

Comment: @bnaul would you be so kind to contribute this back into the dask codebase?

Comment: does this work for non-unique index? I see "value_counts" there

Comment: For a unique index, this will create an entire copy of it in memory. If your data is big enough to need Dask, that might not be feasible.

Comment: Dask now has a `partition_size` kwarg to repartition which does something similar (arguably better) using the size of the data, and without materializing the entire index on one node.